# Is it a material design bug for web

Tags: html, css, material-design

My mdc card has white space on right side after inserting a background (svg).
Example is on codepen https://codepen.io/BhavyaSingh2003/pen/ZwByBy

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.mycard {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Aut.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
<div class="mdc-card mycard">
</div>
```

Please tell how to resolve this as I have to design a signup form with the background and I can't place an image like this because I have put textfields and other stuff on it so it has to be in the background.

Comment: you need to reset margin too : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxbrVM

Comment: i have done that

Comment: but still white space is there

Comment: Do you need shadow or not ?

Comment: You did not reset margin on body ..., but are you talking about image ratio ?

Comment: no shadow needed but after reseting it displays white space approx 10px-15px

Comment: That's not a problem with margins, because `background-position` doesn't consider margins or padding. Actually I can't understand what causes the problem

Comment: what to do now?

Comment: The problem is in your svg, because it has margins

Comment: no it has no margins

Comment: There is a `rect` with `translate(281.22 1965.8) rotate(-63.57)`, this is causing a margin

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/sW0m05J/Screenshot-10.png see this

Comment: how to solve this problem i have the illustrator file for this

Answer (score 0):

### If you like, you add this custom solution. But it's not perfect solution.

```css
body,html{
  height:100%;
margin:0px;
}
.mycard {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}


.mdc-card.mycard:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Aut.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    right: -20%;
    top: 0;
    background-position: right;
    white-space: unset;
}
```

Comment: "" the link to background url

Comment: no luck visit the codepen url once again that i shared to see there is still white space

Comment: problem now has been solved it was because of rect element tilted in the svg